# How to add google authentication in an iframe?

Tags: keycloak, google-authentication

I'm trying to implement google OAuth into an iframe, but i saw that it has blocked due to security issues.

Is there any workaround/customization that can be done to make it work.
Note: I have used keycloak google auth as well.
So it would be great if it can be made possible from keycloak.

Comment: Nope. OAuth implementations will almost always refuse to work within a frame.

Comment: @ceejayoz Interesting why is that? clickjacking?

Comment: Yes. It's specifically mentioned in the OAuth spec. https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-23#section-10.13

Comment: @ceejayoz So there is no way I can do this? any pop-up window to do it or anything?

Answer (score 2):

You can not.  You need to use a pop-up window.

`accounts.google.com` sets `X-Frame-Options` to `deny`