# Open account.google.com authentication in iframe

Tags: reactjs, iframe, google-oauth

I have tried to do authentification in an iframe but the google server returns errors like 
Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
Can somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it normally impossible to open the connection page of google in an iframe because google forbids it cause of some vulnerability. you can link to this post to see for more information : [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66027228/how-to-add-google-authentication-in-an-iframe)